# Returning a file using asp.net mvc?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, httphandler

I have a custom IHttpHandler which is used by thick clients to download files using a url such as

```
http://url.ashx?id=123&version=456
```

the code handler basically ends with

```
context.Response.WriteFile(myLocalServerPath);
```

Is it possible to replace this using the typical asp.net mvc controller pattern ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In an action:

```
byte[] fileBytes = ...;
string fileName = "example";
return File(fileBytes, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet, fileName);
```

(Or a more specific MIME type if known)

Comment: If we returned a more specific MIME, it will just be displayed in the browser (in case if images), how can we download it (by using the more specific MIME)?

Answer (score 0):

From this [site](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=807) but simplified:

```
    public FileResult Download()
    {
        string filename = "test.pdf";
        string contentType = "application/pdf";
        //Parameters to file are
        //1. The File Path on the File Server
        //2. The content type MIME type
        //3. The parameter for the file save by the browser
        return File(filename, contentType,"Report.pdf");
    }
```